# How to GET variables in window.location.hash in node.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, parsing, node.js, express

If I have a url like

```
www.example.com/path#one=a1&two=a2&three=a3
```

How do I retrieve the variables directly from the url in node.js?
Since I am using ExpressJS, I tried using req.query.variable (and req.params.variable), but that wouldn't work...

My actual problem is getting the access token from Facebook, by using the client-side authentication (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/), but the url that it redirects to is structured as so:

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI#
 access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
 &expires_in=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
```

And I don't know how to get the parameters from the url...

Comment: How about 

    url = require('url');
    var url_parts = url.parse(urlString);
    console.log(url_parts);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I retrieve the variables directly from the url in node.js?

Not at all, because the hash part of an URL does not get transmitted to the server.

> My actual problem is getting the access token from Facebook, by using the client-side authentication [...] And I don't know how to get the parameters from the url...

You have to “get” them *client-side* as well.

Comment: Oh wow... how did I not realize that... Thanks! I think I'll try server side instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseQueryString(query) {
    var parsed = {};

    query.replace(
        new RegExp('([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?', 'g'),
        function ($0, $1, $2, $3) {
            parsed[decodeURIComponent($1)] = decodeURIComponent($3);
        }
    );

    return parsed;
}

var url = "www.example.com/path#one=a1&two=a2&three=a3";

console.log(parseQueryString(url.split('#')[1]));
```

Please note that this will not attempt to detect the types of the url parameters.